# Nativescript: Display image from url array from a collection/array using ListView

Tags: image, listview, observable, nativescript

this is the JSON data that I got from a REST API:

[{
"name": "sherwin", 
"field2": "value2",
"field3": "value3",
"images": [{
  "image": "url1", "image":"url2"....}]
"fieldN":"valueN"
}]

... and I have the following ListItem on a page:

```
   <ListView [items]="propertyList" class="image-list" (loaded)="onListViewLoaded($event)">
     <ng-template let-item="item">
       <StackLayout style="height: 200" (tap)="onItemTap(item.id)"
         id="{{item.id}}" (loaded)="onItemLoaded($event, item.images)">
         <StackLayout class="image-container">
           <Image [src]="item.images[0].image" stretch="aspectFill" class="image-content-container"></Image>
         </StackLayout>
         <StackLayout class="image-caption-container">
           <Label id="{{item.id}}"
             [text]="item.propertyName"
               class="image-caption"></Label>
           <Label class="gh-list-description-sub" text="{{item.propertyType}}" textWrap="true"></Label>
         </StackLayout>
       </StackLayout>
     </ng-template>
   </ListView>
```

... but the problem is the image not displaying once the list item were populated.  The 'labels' was displaying though.  I tried data/observable on the code-behind:

export class MainComponent extends Observable implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 private propertyList = new ObservableArray();
... some other codes here

but I am not going anywhere.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some strange behaviour using Image on ListView in the latest NativeScript version 3.1
Images are not displayed until you scroll down and up!!

As a workaround you can use WebImage component from nativescript-web-image-cache plugin.

First install it:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-web-image-cache
```

initialize the plugin on your root component AppComponent, app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/core';
import { initializeOnAngular } from 'nativescript-web-image-cache';

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit():void {
        initializeOnAngular();
    }
}
```

In your template replace Image with WebImage:

```
<StackLayout class="image-container">
           <WebImage [src]="item.images[0].image" stretch="aspectFill" class="image-content-container"></WebImage>
         </StackLayout>
```